# Alternative of WebAuthenticationCoreManager for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth

In UWP I am using `WebAuthenticationCoreManager` to authenticate user in a way similar to OAuth by sending loading some URL and providing "redirect" parameter where user would be redirected after login.

Now, I would like to have similar behavior, but `WebAuthenticationCoreManager` is a part of `System.Windows` namespace, so I can't use it in a web app. Also, for some reason I couldn't find the source code for this class.

**Question**

What is the closest alternative of `WebAuthenticationCoreManager` for web apps and where can I see the source code of this class?